# Meaning of 'excess' in this sentence

Tags: meaning, translation

Can you help me to understand meaning of 'excess'' in sentence below:

> The project may, in fact, be hopeless when it comes to the absolute
>   birth and death of being as meaning – here we can only gesture in
>   the direction of sheer excess.

It's from article on philosophy.

Comment: Could you add more of the context (quote more of the text)? I agree, the meaning of "excess" is not clear here.

Comment: There are several possible meanings, though *sheer excess* usually just uses one of them - but I'm not prepared to give an answer without more information.

Comment: Without more context, the quoted sentence can hardly be said to have a clear meaning. I often encounter sentences in works of philosophy which have little or no meaning even in context. This may perhaps be one, but i can't be sure.

Comment: Seems to be from "Being Shaken: Ontology and the Event". The definition of 'excess' here is charged with context, so you can't ask what it means here without providing the passage and expect us to know it. Maybe this question is actually better off being in philosophy SE, since it doesn't seem that the definition of 'excess' has to do with normal language here.